# Why Composer does not install Laravel 5.6 properly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I am unable to install Laravel 5.6 on my `wamp` server. I have the following setup:

- **PHP Version 7.1.3**
- **Composer Version 1.6.3 2018-01-31**

When I try to install the Laravel application through Composer, I receive the following error in `cmd`:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Counta
> ble in C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\process\Pipes\Windo
> wsPipes.php on line 221

`cmd` returns these errors multiple times and at the end of the error, I get the following message:

> Application ready! Build something amazing.

When I try running this command `php artisan serve` then `cmd` returns the following error:

> Warning: require(D:\wamp64\www\Laravel5.6\PR/vendor/autoload.php): failed to ope
> n stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp64\www\Laravel5.6\PR\artisan on li
> ne 18

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\wamp64\www\Laravel5.6\PR/ven
> dor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp64\www\Laravel5.6\PR
> artisan on line 18

I have searched about it and found a couple of articles. Most of them are saying this is about the PHP version or that I need to update Composer. Some say I need to stop proxy or any anti-virus software.

I have done all the above steps but am still facing the same problem. I still failed to install Laravel 5.6.

**Edited**

After following the instruction of **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146472/why-composer-does-not-installing-laravel-5-6-propoerly?#49148465)**, I face the following errors:

```
[Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
  The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not availab
  le. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error
  , at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--r
epository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no
-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vc
s] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<dir
ectory>] [<version>]
```

The above errors are also in the `cmd`.

Comment: Are you trying to run `artisan serve` within the laravel dir? From your question is looks like you're building the project and then running artisan serve right after

Comment: Did you just upgrade your PHP version? Or the PHP version comes with WAMP installation?

Comment: I update the php version on wamp. Old version was 5.6

Comment: Similar question by the same user (a reposting?): *[Why does Laravel 5.6 not install after updating PHP 7.1.3 on WAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250646/why-does-laravel-5-6-not-install-after-updating-php-7-1-3-on-wamp)*

Answer (score 4):

Laravel 5.6 requires PHP 7.1.3 or later.

*[Installing Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#installing-laravel)*

You don't need 'php artisan serve' if you are running in WAMP or [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP). Just make a virtual host and point your vhost directory to your installation folder blog/public.

Comment: Can you read the question properly before adding the answer. I am already installing through composer as per documentation

Comment: 7.1.14 is greater than 7.1.3, anyway he says he's running 7.1.3

Answer (score 1):

It is not installing because it exists in the cache of your system.

Run the following commands.

```
composer clearcache
```

Also specify the version while creating the project.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.6.*"
```

Make sure you have installed the open-ssl extension in your PHP or run this command:

```
composer config -g -- disable-tls true
```

For installing an extension in Windows, you can simply uncomment this line:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Restart your server and you are good to go.

Comment: I have tried your provided solution and still facing errors but now receiving different error

Comment: I have added error in my question can you kindly have a look

Comment: @user3698265 sure

Comment: @user3698265  `composer config -g -- disable-tls true` run this

Comment: I have done all process but still this message returning `You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
`

Comment: @user3698265  your are on windows? re install composer

Comment: @user3698265 you installed the php_openssl  extension too?

Comment: I have enabled the php_openssl extension from php ini

Comment: Yes I am using windows

Comment: I didn't install open_ssl how to install ?

Comment: @user3698265 open your php.ini and uncomment the line `extension=php_openssl.dll
`