# Why does Laravel 5.6 not install after updating PHP 7.1.3 on WAMP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I am unable to install Laravel 5.6 on my [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants) server. I have following setup

- PHP version 7.1.3
- [Composer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composer_(software)) version 1.6.3 2018-01-31

When I am trying to install the Laravel application through Composer, I am receiving the following error in `cmd`:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\process\Pipes\WindowsPipes.php on line 221

`cmd` is returning these errors multiple times and at the end, the error following message receiving

> Application ready! Build something amazing.

When I am trying to run this command `php artisan serve` then `cmd` returns the following error.

> Warning: require(D:\wamp64\www\Laravel5.6\PR/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp64\www\Laravel5.6\PR\artisan on line 18

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\wamp64\www\Laravel5.6\PR/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp64\www\Laravel5.6\PR\artisan on line 18

I have searched about it and found a couple of articles, but all of them are saying this is about PHP version and some are saying I need to update the Composer and some says I need to stop proxy or any anti-virus software.

I have done all the above steps as instructed in different articles, but I am still facing the same problem. I still failed to install Laravel 5.6.

How can I fix the issue?

After following the instructions of [laravel levaral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146472/why-composer-does-not-installing-laravel-5-6-propoerly?#49148465)'s answer, I am facing the following errors.

> [Composer\Exception\NoSslException] 
> The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available.
> If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error,
> at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.
>
> create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [] [] []

The above errors are also in the `cmd`.

I have tried all the methods in the answers, but I am still facing the errors.

Comment: Have you tried installing open-ssl?

Comment: Yes I had installed it

Comment: did you try a composer du ?

Comment: @kevinniel No I didn't try composer du. What is this

Comment: try this `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` - it often resolve composer issues. I'm using it each time i'm updating composer or before changing migrations

Comment: @laravellevaral I had tried several times but still failed

Comment: @user3698265  try composer update/install

Comment: @user3698265 have you changed the values in `php.ini` enabled the extension?\

Comment: @laravellevaral Yes I did in `php.ini` according to your instructions

Comment: tried reinstalling composer with the latest binary file?

Comment: @laravellevaral No that's what I didn't tried

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166733/discussion-between-laravel-levaral-and-user3698265).

Comment: did you add php7.1 path to `environment variable` ?

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara No how to add ?

Comment: just go to your php installation path (probably `C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.3`) copy that path to environment variable [this explain step by step](https://john-dugan.com/add-php-windows-path-variable/)

Comment: The file path in one of the error messages contains a mix of (forward) slashes and backslashes: `D:\wamp64\www\Laravel5.6\PR/vendor/autoload.php`

Answer (score -1):

Try to install the latest version of WAMP and check with the below command:

```
    composer update --no-scripts
    composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score -2):

Try running

`composer update`

in your project folder and it should install the vendor package that you need in order to run  your project.

Comment: I have found a post that might help you but can't do much more sorry 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249620/the-openssl-extension-is-required-for-ssl-tls-protection

Comment: "Try running" sounds fine. Can you explain that further? Why should updating packages solve an error thrown by Composer itself?

Answer (score -3):

The failure to install Laravel 5.6 after updating PHP to 7.1.3 on Wamp is caused by the absence of the OpenSSL extension, which is necessary for SSL/TLS encryption. You can do the actions listed below to address this issue:

1. Locate your PHP configuration file (`php.ini`) for the PHP version you updated (in this case, PHP 7.1.3). It is typically found in the Wamp installation directory under `bin\php\php7.1.3`.
2. Use a text editor to access the "php.ini" file.
3. Search for the following line: `;extension=openssl`.
4. To uncomment a line, remove the semicolon (;) at the beginning of the line. 'extension=openssl' ought to now be visible.
5. Save the changes to the `php.ini` file and close the text editor.
6. To implement the configuration changes, restart the Wamp server..

You should be able to use the 'create-project' command you supplied to continue installing Laravel 5.6 after enabling the OpenSSL extension. Verify that Composer is set up and available from the command line. Run the command line:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <directory> "5.6.*"
```

Wherever you wish to install Laravel 5.6, replace "" with the relevant directory name. This command will use the 5.6 version to start a new Laravel project.

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT

Comment: The steps are same everytime

Comment: [The comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250646/why-laravel-5-6-does-not-installing-after-updating-php-7-1-3-on-wamp/76422454#comment85504545_49250646) to the question contains *"Have you tried installing* ***open-ssl?"*** and *"Yes I had installed it"*. How does that jive with the leading statement *"The failure to install Laravel 5.6 after updating PHP to 7.1.3 on Wamp is caused by the* ***absence of the OpenSSL extension"***? (My emphasis)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy